# Hortonworks HDP2.0 + giraph

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, giraph

I have hortonworks HDP2.0 running in sandbox (recently installed) at Windows 8.1 platform. I need to learn how to get giraph working with HDP 2.0,.

I think, giraph is not currently installed with HDP 2.0 bydefault. Can someone help me installing giraph as well as point me to some sources on hands-on coding tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining [this hortonworks MapReduce tutorial](https://github.com/hortonworks/hadoop-tutorials/blob/master/Community/T09_Write_And_Run_Your_Own_MapReduce_Java_Program_Poll_Result_Analysis.md) and the [Giraph Quick Start](https://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html).

The former shows you how to create a shared folder and copy files between your local and virtual machines.  Create a Giraph jar (using the second link), place in the hue Home Directory, give it relevant permissions, and create an input file (as detailed in first link).

When creating the Giraph jar you will need to compile against Hadoop 2 - I did this using the command `mvn -Phadoop_2.0.0 package` from the Giraph root directory.

Depending on the version of Giraph you are using you may have problems with running as described in the second link, I found

`hadoop jar giraph.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsVertex -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /user/hue/tinygraph.txt -of org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/hue/output/shortestpaths -w 1`

worked for me (note the difference in the specifying the output format using -of instead of -vof, and using SimpleShortestPathsVertex instead of SimpleShortestPathsComputation.

When running the jar I ran into an exception

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "checkLocalJobRunnerConfiguration: When using
"LocalJobRunner, you cannot run in split master / worker mode since there is only 1 task at a time!"`

which I fixed by adding the line

```
job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("giraph.SplitMasterWorker", false);
```

to org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.java in giraph-core.

I also ran into problems with ZooKeeper ports, which I detailed with a work around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393259/giraph-zookeeper-port-problems).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You! Tutorial is of great help!

Answer (score 0):

I have used FBUnicorn's answer above to compile a full guide on how to achieve installing Giraph 1.2.0 on top of a freshly deployed instance of Hortonworks (HDP 2.2).

I have deployed HDP using a VirualBox as the VM would have internet connectivity out-of-the-box, which was not the case with the VMware equivalent.

These are the few steps:

**Clone the Giraph git repository**

```
cd /usr/local/
sudo git clone https://github.com/apache/giraph.git
```

**Add user to CentOS**

```
useradd -G hadoop hduser
sudo passwd hduser
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop giraph
su - hduser
```

**Install Maven (mvn) on CentOS (w/ the help of [this](http://preilly.me/2013/05/10/how-to-install-maven-on-centos/) article)**

```
wget http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/maven/maven-3/3.0.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz -C /usr/local
cd /usr/local
sudo ln -s apache-maven-3.0.5 maven
```

**Maven setup**

```
sudo vi /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

Insert

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Log out and log back in. Ensure that version 3 or greater of maven is available.

```
mvn -version
```

**Export Hadoop and Giraph directories**

```
vi $HOME/.bashrc
```

Add

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop
export GIRAPH_HOME=/usr/local/giraph
```

**Modify GraphRunner.java as per FBUnicorn
answer** (/usr/local/giraph/giraph-core/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph)

```
job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("giraph.SplitMasterWorker", false);
```

before boolean verbose = !cmd.hasOption('q');

**Compile Giraph**

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
cd $GIRAPH_HOME
mvn -Phadoop_2 -fae -DskipTests clean install
```

Check that the jars are generated in the $GIRAPH_HOME/giraph-core/target/ folder

**Create a test example with a tiny graph**

```
vi /tmp/tiny_graph.txt
```

Insert

```
[0,0,[[1,1],[3,3]]]
[1,0,[[0,1],[2,2],[3,1]]]
[2,0,[[1,2],[4,4]]]
[3,0,[[0,3],[1,1],[4,4]]]
[4,0,[[3,4],[2,4]]]
```

**Created HDFS folder:**

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hduser/input
```

**Copy the graph to HDFS**
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /tmp/tiny_graph.txt /user/hduser/input/tiny_graph.txt

Check that file made it to the HDFS repository 
hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/input

**Process Giraph graph**

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /user/hduser/input/tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/hduser/output/shortestpaths -w 1
```