# Giraph ZooKeeper port problems

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, giraph

I am trying to run the SimpleShortestPathsVertex (aka SimpleShortestPathComputation) example described in the [Giraph Quick Start](https://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html).  I am running this on a Hortonworks Sandbox instance (HDP 2.1) using VirtualBox, and I packaged giraph.jar using profile hadoop_2.0.0.

When I try to run the example using

```
hadoop jar giraph.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner 
org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsVertex -vif 
org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip 
/user/hue/tinygraph.txt -of org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat 
-op /user/hue/output/shortestpaths -w 1
```

I get the following exception

```
2014-04-30 07:22:15,390 INFO [main] org.apache.giraph.zk.ZooKeeperManager: onlineZooKeeperServers: Connect attempt 0 of 10 max trying to connect to sandbox.hortonworks.com:22181 with poll msecs = 3000
2014-04-30 07:22:15,396 WARN [main] org.apache.giraph.zk.ZooKeeperManager: onlineZooKeeperServers: Got ConnectException
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.giraph.zk.ZooKeeperManager.onlineZooKeeperServers(ZooKeeperManager.java:701)
at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager.startZooKeeperManager(GraphTaskManager.java:357)
at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager.setup(GraphTaskManager.java:188)
at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphMapper.setup(GraphMapper.java:60)
at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphMapper.run(GraphMapper.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

I have found a work around - it seems that Giraph expects ZooKeeper to be running on port 22181, while it is actually running on 2181.  I have simply used the Ambari interface to set ZooKeeper to run on 22181 (go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`, login admin/admin, Services tab, ZooKeeper and change the port to 22181, save and Service Actions -> Restart All.

Does anyone have a better solution for this problem?  Is there a config via which the port should be specified, or is this port in the Giraph source code a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can specify each time you run a Giraph job via using option `-Dgiraph.zkList=localhost:2181`

Also you can set it up in Hadoop configs and then you don't have to pass on this option each time you submit a Giraph job. For that add the following line in `conf/core-site.xml` file :

`<property><name>giraph.zkList</name><value>localhost:2181</value></property>`

[Please check the syntax, I don't recall it on top my head and currently I don't have access to a cluster to check it]